# force connect wifi to a specific BSSID

Tags: centos, wifi

(I'm intentionally imprecise with the actual steps i've tried because there are hundreds of things - I know because I looked at the size of my BASH history)

CentOS 7, NetworkManager

(Please correct anything i'm wrong about below)

A customer has an environment with multiple APs having the same SSID. I have to write a BASH script that connects a linux box to each AP in turn, executes a command to gather data, then moves on to the next AP, wash, rinse, repeat. The BSSID is the obvious thing to use to connect. The script qua script is working beautifully, but the BSSID-based wifi connection bit is not.

I have tried iw, iwconfig, nmcli, and wpa_supplicant and cannot get it to reliably connect to the BSSID I specify - regardless of what I put in the command the actual BSSID connected to just seems to be random. From what I have gathered, all of these tools, aside from wpa_supplicant, just take the BSSID, associate it with an SSID, then use the SSID in the connection setup, which, if correct, seems kinda stupid (to be blunt).

wpa_supplicant is just too fragile to use this way - it always gets into a state where wpa_cli cannot connect and I have to continually restart it and often restart NetworkManager.

I thought about switching to Python, but the Python modules just seem to be wrappers to the linux commands, so nothing changes.

If anyone has any ideas please pass them along. I cannot believe that this is so difficult, so I must be missing something obvious...

I tried Eduardo's solution below.

I cannot implement this exactly as provided. I'm running the connection attempt in a loop in a shell script where the MAC address / BSSID is a variable (SSID and password/psk are static).

The command i'm using to connect is:

```
nmcli connection up ifname wlp4s0 ap $AP passwd-file passwdfile
```

where passwdfile contains the psk. This is in a loop through the list of $AP.

It still connects to a random AP from the list. (Probably the one that at that instant had the best signal), and more confusing (to me) is that `iw` event shows a different connected BSSID than

```
nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | grep yes
```

There must be something really obvious i'm not doing correctly (this is still mostly new to me).

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to connect through Wi-Fi instead of LAN using IP addresses?

Comment: yes - the purpose is to gather some stats from the APs about the wifi connection to the test device, so it has to connect. And i think to use the IP via ethernet the target IPs would have to be configured ahead of time. I get the ssid/bssid automatically using a scan. The idea is to have a standard load for the test devices that requires little to no config before they are deployed - ship it to the customer, plug it in, and go.

Answer (score 0):

If you only provide the normal ascii password then `wpa_supplicant` needs to find out the SSID, because the 64 hex digits PSK (kind of the actual password) is derived from it. At this moment it goes into SSID mode.

So the solution is to specify just the BSSID and the **64 hex digits PSK** password.

You can get the 64 hex digits PSK by running:

```
wpa_passphrase YourSSID YourAsciiPassword
```

For example:

```
$ wpa_passphrase Example myexample
network={
    ssid="Example"
    #psk="myexample"
    psk=e22b519be7138dce1d81d1b67b622a720774f22753f79f954376e6e2b722e2c7
}
```

Then you use BSSID instead of SSID and end up with something like this:

```
network={
  bssid=EE:FF:00:01:02:03
  psk=e22b519be7138dce1d81d1b67b622a720774f22753f79f954376e6e2b722e2c7
}
```

That should connect you just to that BSSID.

Comment: great - i will give that a try and see what happens.